# What is the significance of Raymond in 6 Underground?

Tags: plot-explanation, 6-underground

Just watching the movie *6 Underground*. At around 1:05,

> 1 asks who the other guy at the table is and it’s “Raymond”

What is the significance of this interaction, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That scene was filmed in Hong Kong, and the dining culture is different at small eateries. A server will sit customers in a manner that would fill up one table before moving onto the next table. So, you occasionally get random strangers sitting next to you while eating your bowl of wanton mee.

I guess its significance is to highlight an instance of Hong Kong culture.

Comment: I don’t know what this was downvoted. It seems like the most likely explanation to me.

Comment: Raymond was also the 'setup' for One's subsequent chiding of the group and Two in particular regarding security.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if maybe _Raymond_ was a cameo or if there was some back story here, but I guess it's just as it seemed.